# SqlAlchemy mysql millisecond or microsecond precision

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, sqlalchemy, milliseconds

I've been venturing down the odyssey of trying to get fractional time resolution working properly in my database. I use the python method `datetime.now()` in order to create date objects. I then store these objects in a field which is mapped to a `COLUMN(DATETIME(9))` which is from SqlAlchemy's library. Originally, I was getting an error that my data was being truncated. This is because I was using mysql 5.5. I have since updated to 5.6.19 and no longer get the data truncated error.

However, the database still does not actually contain fractional time entries. For example, here is the value from when the datetime.now() object is instantiated:

```
2015-04-17 16:31:12.804444
```

The above is exactly what I would expect. The object in memory has microsecond resolution. Now, after it saves this to the mysql database, I see the following value if I open the mysql command line client and return the row using a select statement:

```
2015-04-17 16:31:13
```

Obviously, the value is being rounded to the nearest second. This is bad, and I have no idea what is causing it!

In case it is relevant, I'm using mysql-connector-python==2.0.3

UPDATE:
I also tried using `COLUMN(DATETIME(6))`, but got the same behavior.

I am below including the model, in case that information is relevant:

```
class User(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'Users'

        uid = Column(INT, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
        dateCreated = Column(DATETIME(6))

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(user, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                self.dateCreated = datetime.now()
```

UPDATE:
Pedro's suggestion wasn't the problem, though it definitely helped me make progress, so big thanks. I tried stepping through code in the sql connector until I got to the mysql insert statement. The statement does indeed contain the fractional time value. However, when executed, the value is rounded. When I did a describe on the table, I noticed that the datetime type is just that, `datetime` when it should really be `datetime(6)`.

I'm generating the database itself using the SA model,which explicitly declares `Column(DATETIME(6))` , and `Base.metadata.create_all(self.db, checkfirst=True)` , so I don't understand why the (6) isn't ending up in the actual table structure. I think I'll figure it out shortly though, and I'll post an update when I do.

UPDATE:
The constructor to DATETIME does not accept field length specification. It only takes an argument for timezones. It isn't clear to me how to specify the length of a datetime field, since for types like varchar one would just pass it in to the constructor. The dive continues.

Comment: You "end up with this" when you select the values back into Python? View them with the `mysql` command-line tool or some GUI tool?

Comment: Also, according to [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html), "The fsp value, if given, must be in the range 0 to 6. A value of 0 signifies that there is no fractional part. If omitted, the default precision is 0." So, are you sure `DATETIME(9)` isn't treating the 9 as "not in the range 0 to 6, ignore and use the default (which is 0)"?

Comment: Also, can you insert values with microseconds using some other tool? It would help to rule out which side of mysql-connector-python the problem is on…

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem I was having is that the stock SqlAlchemy DATETIME class does not work with the mysql requirement of passing a (6) value into the constructor in order to represent fractional time values. Instead, one needs to use the `sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.DATETIME` class. This class allows the use of the `fsp` parameter (fractional seconds parameter.) So, a column declaration should actually look like:

```
dateCreated = Column(DATETIME(fsp=6))
```

Thanks to those others who replied. It helped guide my investigation to ultimately stumbling over this esoteric and very confusing distinction.

Comment: Reference to docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html
; search for `sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.DATETIME`

Comment: I haven't actually tested this, but `with_variant` may be useufl, `Column.Datetime().with_variant(mysql.DATETIME(fsp=6), 'mysql')` https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_api.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeEngine.with_variant may be useful - it would allow for setting this only for mysql databases

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an open issue with MySQLdb, not MySQL or SQLAlchemy.

http://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/feature-requests/24/

You can try using another MySQL driver library -- check [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#dialect-mysql) for supported options --, or you can try the monkeypatch suggested in the open issue.

Comment: Is there a way to know which mysql driver supports this feature?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html), it only supports precision up to 6 places (microseconds):

"MySQL 5.6.4 and up expands fractional seconds support for TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision"

I don't know for sure, but specifying 9 digits might be reverting the column to a smaller default precision.

Answer (score 0):

In order to force using fractional seconds precision in MySQL while keeping the defaults on other engines you could modify how SQLAlchemy compiles the `DateTime` type for MySQL.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.types import DateTime
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import DATETIME

@compiles(DateTime, "mysql")
def compile_datetime_mysql(type_, compiler, **kw):
     return "DATETIME(6)"
```

It is basically telling sql alchemy to compile the `DateTime` with a custom type only for mysql ,in our case returning `DATETIME(6)` where the parameter with value 6 is the fsp (fractional seconds precision [from MySQL 5.6.4])